# Should I be using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like so:

```
'cathy is a singer on fridays'
```

and I want to be able to replace the fourth word with other verbs

so

```
'cathy is a dancer on fridays'
```

I assumed the right way to do this would be to use regex and stop when you reach the third whitespace but you can do groupings with regex and * which accepts any char. I can't seem to get it working.

Any advice would be useful. I am new to Python so please dont judge.Also is regex appropriate for this or should I use another method?

Thank you

Comment: Why would [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) not work for you? Are there other constraints?

Comment: singer is not a verb

Comment: admittedly you are asking the right question ("how do I do this?  is regex the right tool?") rather than the wrong question ("how do I do this with regex?") so +1.

Comment: @Hoopdady Haha, neither is dancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Regex is not needed for this.  See below:

```
>>> mystr = 'cathy is a singer on fridays'
>>> x = mystr.split()
>>> x
['cathy', 'is', 'a', 'singer', 'on', 'fridays']
>>> x[3] = "dancer"
>>> x
['cathy', 'is', 'a', 'dancer', 'on', 'fridays']
>>> " ".join(x)
'cathy is a dancer on fridays'
```

Or, more compact:

```
>>> mystr = 'cathy is a singer on fridays'
>>> x = mystr.split()
>>> " ".join(x[:3] + ["dancer"] + x[4:])
'cathy is a dancer on fridays'
>>>
```

The core principle here is the [`.split`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method of a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want by splitting and joining the string after substituting the desired piece

```
stringlist = 'cathy is a singer on fridays'.split()
stringlist[3] = 'dancer'
print(' '.join(stringlist))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution using backreferences and the `sub` function from `re`

Documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
import re

msg = 'cathy is a singer on fridays'
print re.sub('(\w+) (\w+) (\w+) (\w+)', r'\1 \2 \3 dancer', msg, 1)
```

Output

```
>>> cathy is a dancer on fridays
```

Answer (score 0):

if you really just want the third word, split/slice/join is easier:

```
mytext = 'cathy is a singer on fridays'

mysplit = mytext.split(' ')
' '.join(mysplit[:3] + ['dancer',] + mysplit[4:])
```

regex can do much more complicated things, and there is a re.split, and there might be a faster way to do it, but this is reasonable and readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can either split the string using `split(' ')` or a tokenizer like nltk which might also provide you some more functionality for this specific use case with part of speech analysis. If you are trying to replace it with random nouns of profession look for a word bank. Regex is overkill for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the position of the word you want to replace in the string, you could simply use:

```
def replace_word(sentence, new_word, position):
    sent_list = sentence.split()
    sent_list[position] = new_word
    return " ".join(sent_list)
```